# How to load data from a file as array using numpy in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I need to load data from a data file which looks like this:

```
       3
       3
       3
       1
       1
       1
       0
       1
       1
       1
       1
       1
       1
       1
       0
       0
       1
       0
       1
       1
       1
       1
       1
       3
       3
       3
       2
       3
       3
       3
       3
       3
       3
       3
       3
       3
       0
       0
       3
       2
       2
       0
       2
       2
       2
       2
       2
       2
```

These are values of a 2X2 matrix each point having assigned to a value 0,1,2 or 3. I need to load these data and assign them to a variable say 'lattice' like this:

```
       3 3 3 1 1 1 2
       0 0 2 3 3 3 2
       1 1 2 2 2 2 1
       0 0 0 2 3 1 0
       1 2 1 2 2 2 2
       3 2 3 2 3 3 3
```

But when I load file like this:

```
import numpy as np
data2 = np.loadtxt('latticeData', delimiter = ',')
lattice= data
```

('latticeData' is the data file name)
This gives me oneD array of all the values assigned to it.
How can I split these in 2D array as required?

Comment: Reshape the loaded data by using `.reshape`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
req_data = np.reshape(data2,(num_rows,num_cols))
```

Answer (score 1):

Reshape the data with `.reshape((6,-1))` after loading. Also you can try loading the data with pandas and then converting it into ndarray with `.values()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

arr = np.loadtxt('array.txt').reshape(6, -1)

arr.ndim
OUTPUT: 2